# How to not show tableView until all cell data is finished loading in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, cell

I have a tableView but when it loads the cells it looks ugly because the images take a second or two to load in. I have a loader that I want to display and then when all the cells have loaded in I want to show the tableView and hide loader. How can I tell when the tableView is finished loading and show the tableView?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
    let payment = self.payments[indexPath.row]
            if let profileImageUrl = payment.picture {
                cell.profilePicture.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageUrl)
                cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2
                cell.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
            }

    if payment.message == "none" {
        cell.detailsLabel.text = "No Message"
    } else {
        cell.detailsLabel.text = "\"\(payment.message ?? "")\""
    }

        cell.amountLabel.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 105/255, green: 105/255, blue: 105/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.amountLabel.text = "$\(payment.amount ?? "")"
          
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What about using SDWebImage (or other KingFisher, Alamofire+Image) that should have spinner while downloading: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/How-to-use#use-view-indicator-50

Comment: I have a custom loader I want to use though, in the middle of my screen...

Comment: You want to download ALL the images and then reload the tableView with the loaded images? Look for DispatchGroup, enter, leave, notify then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to show `Activity Indicator` to warn/show your user to wait for a while **until visible cells get loaded** properly, correct?

You have your custom loader (`Activity Indicator`) that you want to display *after all the cells have loaded in* as you wrote.

One thing which is important to understand here is that `UITableView` is **not** gonna load **all** cells because it doesn't work that way.

No matter how many items you have, the table view will only use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to create 6 or 7 cells (depends) that are visible.

If a user scrolls, then the method above will be called again for new ***visible*** cells.

So this means that

> the table never really finishes loading.

Answering the question on how to detect if the table finished loading *visible* cells, then you may try this piece of code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let lastVisibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last {
                if indexPath == lastVisibleIndexPath {
                    // turn off/hide your loader
                }
        }
    }
```